# SonataAdmin on Symfony2 - edit inline choice

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, inline-editing

I'm having trouble with the Sonata Admin Bundle, which runs on Symfony2.

I have an entity with an enum field, which I converted to string, because there are no enums available.

I used `choice` as a type of the list view, and provided my options. Works great in edit view - I can select from a list of options, and the actual value from DB is highlighted.

But I would like to be able to edit this inline (in list view, not in edit). I've added `'editable' => true`, which works great, but the type of field I'm getting in edit is a simple text one - I can input anything there.

I've tried all the miracles I could find online, and nothing helps.

This works by default on the boolean types - it indicates `yes` and `no` (green and red) buttons, and when I click any, I get a select box with the two options to chose from. And all that happens inline.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: I m very intersted by such a feature :D

Comment: Come on guys, any ideas? :)

Comment: I just took a look in this. I'm not sure if it's the right way, but I think you could try to owerride sonata_xeditable_type twig filter, so it return 'select' for field of type 'choice', later on override (or just switch it in listMapper) the template CRUD/list_choice.html.twig so it depend on field_description.options.editable just like in /CRUD/list_boolean.html.twig

:-)   seems a bit complicated at least

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will try this solution and check what's going on. I was sure I can make it by overriding those templates and methods, but I was hoping it won't be that hard as long as it seems so simple and obvious one..

Comment: Have you found a solution @AndreyPopov ? Otherwise I think they are working on this issue / feature: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/1023

Comment: I still can't understand this. I've browsed for 2 hours and got into 10 different requests/posts/merges. It seems they haven't implemented it yet, and I can't imagine I'll override several files just to get such a simple inline edit for choices (your date example is a bit more reasonable).

Comment: I'm currently watching the following issues and waiting for good news too! - https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/2324   - https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/2269